# DJANGO initial values in form not shown in template (some do some don't)

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have these Models, Tipos, Prioridad and Estado, related to Tarea

as defined below:

```
class Tipos(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=16,
                            verbose_name='tipo')
    abrv = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tipo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tipos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipo


class Prioridad(models.Model):
    prioridad = models.CharField(max_length=16,
                                 verbose_name='prioridad')
    abrv = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            default='')
    orden = models.IntegerField(u'orden', blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Prioridad"
        verbose_name_plural = "Prioridades"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prioridad


class Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=16,
                              verbose_name='estado')
    abrv = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Estado"
        verbose_name_plural = "Estados"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.estado


class Tarea(models.Model):
    numtar = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                related_name='user_cliente',
                                null=True,
                                on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    apoyo = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              related_name='user_apoyo',
                              null=True,
                              on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    asignado = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                 related_name='user_asignado',
                                 null=True,
                                 on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    descorta = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    deslarga = models.TextField(max_length=8195)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado,
                               null=True,
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipos,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    prioridad = models.ForeignKey(Prioridad,
                                  null=True,
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    revision = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    cierre = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tarea"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tareas"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (str(self.numtar))
```

and I call the following view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def newincid_view(request):
    perfil = ExUserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    prioridad_media = Prioridad.objects.get(prioridad='Media')
    estado_abierta = Estado.objects.get(estado='Abierta')
    tipo_incidencia = Tipos.objects.get(tipo='Incidencia')

    datos_apertura = {'cliente': perfil.user,
                      'tipo': tipo_incidencia,
                      'prioridad:': prioridad_media,
                      'estado': estado_abierta
                      }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = newincidForm(request.POST,initial=datos_apertura)
        if form.is_valid():
            tar=form.save(commit=True)
            apertura = TipoNota.objects.get(tiponota='Apertura')
            anotacion = Nota(numtar=tar, tiponota=apertura,
                             anotador=perfil.user,
                             contenido='Incidencia Abierta')
            anotacion.save()
    else:
        form = newincidForm(initial=datos_apertura)

    return render(request, "incid/newincid.html", {'form':form})
```

with this form:

```
class newincidForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tarea
        exclude = ['numtar', 'creacion', 'revision', 'cierre']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(newincidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['descorta'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control no-resize'
        self.fields['deslarga'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control no-resize autogrowth'
```

and this template:

```
{% extends "incid/base_incid.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load static %}
{% load logo %}
{% load i18n %}     <!-- Hooks para poder hacerlo multilingüe -->
{% load tags_html %}

{% block css %}

{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="{% static 'adminbsb/plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <h4 style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px">NUEVA INCIDENCIA</h4>
        </div>
            <div class="body">
                <form  action= "{% url 'incid:newincid' %}" method="post" class="form">
                     {% csrf_token %}
                        {% bootstrap_form form %}
                         {% buttons %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        {% endbuttons %}
                </form>
                {{ form.errors }}
            </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

extending a standard base with no references to either prioridad, tipo or estado.

Nevertheless, when rendered, **tipo** and **estado** show the initial values but **prioridad** doesn't. I have rewritten view, form and template from scratch twice as I couldn't find a typo but it still happens. I would appreciate any clues or hints on what to do.

*Note: This is a revisitation of another problem I posted that I do not know how to delete or edit.*

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it. It was something as silly as that I had included the semicolon into the quotes in the datos_apertura definition:

It was written this way:
**'prioridad:': prioridad_media,**
when it should have been
**'prioridad': prioridad_media**
Several days lost in such idiocy. An error should raise if I try to initiate an unknown field of a form ,Shouldn't it?. Also if PyCharm didn't take every thing as typos I wouldn't have had it silenced.

Thanks a lot and thanks for the patience in reading my posts.